# Submit button becomes not disable but it doesn't have be disable when check on number format

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-forms

I use angular and I use Form and in particular the Template driven form. In particular I have a number that can be major to zero and it must have two decimal places so:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()" #search="ngForm">
  <input type="text" ngModel class="form-control" name="search_Home" required min=0>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!search.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that when I don't put anything the button is disabled but if I put the value "-3" the button became clickable but it is not correct.Anyone can help me?

Comment: Reactive form is better in this way ,template form meant for simple forms

Comment: In template driven you need to create a custom validator to verify min value required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()" #search="ngForm">
  <input type="text" [ngModel]="searchHome" (input)="isNumber($event)" class="form-control" name="search_Home" required min=0>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="isFormValid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Component:**

```js
isBtnSubmitDisabled = true;

isNumber(value) {
  if(value && /* cond */) {
    this.isBtnSubmitDisabled = false;
  }
}

get isFormValid() {
  return this.isBtnSubmitDisabled;
}
```